# JavaScript chegando ao número 100

Tags: javascript

Estou com problema em uma soma no JavaScript, exemplo 188/100 = 1.88*100 = 188, mas não quero que chegue a 188, quero que o número sempre chegue ao número 100.

> 188/100*100 = 100

Pessoal eu consegui é simples!

```
i = 50; 
100/i*i;
```

Comment: Pode explicar com outras paravras e mais exemplos o que pretende? está pouco claro para mim.

Comment: @Sergio um numero que 188 vezes chegue ao numero 100

Comment: Não entendi nada! `100/i*i == 100`?

Comment: @utluiz 100/50*50 = 100

Comment: @DieguinhoRodrigues Me expressei mal. Qual o propósito disso? É um princípio básico da matemática que você pode "anular" um mesmo número que esteja tanto no numerador quanto no denominador?

Comment: @utluiz eu estou fazendo uma função q pode me manda qualquer numero, ai fiz uma barra de pogresso ate o 100, e so pensei nessa alternativa.

Comment: Ahhh!!! Então o que você quer é algo [assim](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/Wtw2B/)?

Comment: sim, mais ja resolvi

Answer (score 5):

Se você quer um número que multiplicado por 188 dê 100 como resultado, basta fazer:

```
fator = 100/188; // Perceba que usei 100/188 e não 188/100

cem = fator * 188; // Vai dar 100 (com algum possível problema de arredondamento)
```

<sub>Nota: esta resposta foi dada antes da edição da pergunta, usando um método dedutivo complexo (chamado chute). De qualquer forma, parece ter solucionado o problema do OP. Para ver a pergunta original, [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/21224/revisions).</sub>

Comment: Obrigado cara consegui resolver o problema

Answer (score 2):

Troque a vírgula por ponto. Em Javascript, o separador decimal é o ponto ;)

i.e.:

```
1,88 * 100 // 8800
```

Isso ocorre porque o interpretador enxerga isso como:

```
1;
88 * 100;
```

Já o código abaixo se aproxima mais do que você quer:

```
1.88 * 100; // 188;
```

Outra coisa. Se você quer dividir um número em 100 partes iguais, continue com esse raciocínio. Se você quer que um número chegue a 100 em exatas 100 iterações de adição, então comece do 0 e vá incrementando até chegar a 100. A forma mais clássica, e a primeira frase arcana que a maioria dos programadores aprende, é a seguinte:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```